# How to have a variable increase over time (JS)

Tags: javascript, variables

i was wondering how to make a variable go up over time, ive tried to do this -->

```
var i = 1;
var c = document.getElementById("click");
function workers() {
 if (click >= workers*50000)) {
  click += -(workers*50000)
  click += i++
  c.innerHTML = click;
 }
}
```

but it hasnt worked, how do i fix this?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? See https://xyproblem.info/.

Comment: `workers` is a function - why are you multiplying it by `50000`? What did you expect that to do? What is `click`?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this

```
let i = 0;

// instead of 2000 insert the frequency of the wanted update (in milliseconds)
const incrementInterval = setInterval(() => i++, 2000) 

// when you want it to stop it
clearInterval(incrementInterval)
```

anyway, i don't really understand how the code supplied with the question has anything to do with it

Comment: oh sorry, i was meaning to ask is, im making a clicker game to test out code, but i want to have workers idely gain cash over time, but i have the variable click which is the dollar amount you have (its dumb formatting, i know) but i dont know how to make it go upwards incramentally with the variable, the worker variable is the price scaling so that it isnt just an infinite money upgrader, im wondering how to make a variable go up over time and thats about it, sorry for the bad explanation i didnt really know how to word it, thanks for the answers though.

Answer (score 0):

You have an element and a variable 'click', which tells me you're really not wanting to grow over time per se, but rather grow with every click.

Another difficulty is finding out what you're trying to do with multiplying by 50000.  I am assuming you are trying to reset the count after 50000.

One big thing you're missing is the actual association of the click event to your 'click' HTML element.   Below, I'm using `addEventListener` to do that.  From there, I'm resetting the counter to '1' if 'i' goes above '5' (I use 5 just to show the reset in a reasonable number of clicks).  Then I take the value of 'i' and put it into the innerHTML label of the element that triggered the event.

```js
var i = 1;

document
  .getElementById("click")
  .addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (i > 5)
        i = 1;
      e.target.innerHTML = `click: ${i++}`;
  })
```

```html
<div id='click'>click<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your question better. What is your goal? What has your code achieved? What result are you getting and how is it different than your expectations? What is 'i' meant to be used for? How does it interact with the function? Why are you multiplying it with 50000? Is workers a separate variable that's globally defined and not shown? Communication is an important skill in this field, and comments are often helpful tools to document your code for others to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think an alternative answer could be formatted in this way:

```js
let i = 0;

function increment(){
  i++;
  
  document.querySelector('h3').textContent = i
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',increment)
```

```html
<button>Click Me</button>
<h3>0</h3>
```